# Can we use agTextColumnFilter and agSetColumnFilter both in one column?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid in my project and need to use agTextColumnFilter and agSetColumnFilter in one column.

So is this possible?

Or can we both agTextColumnFilter and agSeColumnFilter in a custom filter component?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use two filters on the same column, but of course, you can write a custom filter, and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can, as long as you have an Enterprise license. Refer to the [agMultiColumnFilter documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/26.2.0/angular-data-grid/filter-multi/). This filter, as stated in the documentation, combines both by default. Otherwise, you will need to create custom filters (as already suggested). That documentation, for custom filters, can be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-filter/).

Edit: agMultiColumnFilter was revamped or added in [version 24.0.0](https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=24.0.0). According to documentation, it does not exist before that.